# Sign of a Fisher Information changes depending on the formula I use

Tags: statistics, fisher-information

I am trying to compute the Fisher Information for θ in the following scenario:

```
 X_1, X_2, ... , X_n are independent and identically distributed from a Uniform (0, θ)
```

There are 2 different but equivalent formulas for the Fisher info:

```
-E(∂^2/∂θ^2 (ln (f(x|θ))) =   E(∂/∂θ (ln (f(x|θ)))^2
```

Now, with the first formula I get `-1/θ^2`, while with the Second one I get `1/θ^2`. (the sign changes)

How is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There are additional assumptions in the first formula regarding interchange of derivative and integral which do not hold here.

Comment: More importantly, Fisher information is usually interpreted for 'regular' distributions ($U(0,\theta)$ is non-regular with support depending on parameter).

Comment: @StubbornAtom so, since it is not regular, the Fisher Information is taken with absolute value?

Comment: For non-regular distributions, I don't know what Fisher information is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisher's Information is defined only for Cramer-Rao regular families of distributions. One of the Cramer-Rao regularity conditions is:

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta \theta}f_{\theta}(x)  \forall x, \forall \theta$$

exists finite, which in turn implies the support of $x$ being independent of $\theta$. Per contraposition, if such condition is violated, then the derivative doesn't exist finite, hence the distribution is not Cramer-Rao regular and Fisher's Information doesn't exist. Also, it is not always true the two definitions to be interchangeable, an additional regularity condition is needed.

Let me add - hence moving from comment to answer for space - that when computing the derivative of a distribution with respect to a parameter, you can't ignore the fact that it is in the support, since it instead becomes not computable.

To make it clear:

$$X \sim U(0, \theta) \Rightarrow f_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}I(0 < x < \theta)$$

whose derivative is not computable. Finally, note that the two definitions of the Fisher are equivalent if and only if:

$$\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta \theta^{2}}\int f_{\theta}(x)dx =\int \frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta \theta^{2}} f_{\theta}(x)dx $$

which is not necessarily true. If does not hold, the definition of Fisher Information is:

$$I^{x}(\theta) = E_{\theta}  \left [ \left (  \frac{\delta}{\delta \theta} ln(f_{\theta}(x)) \right )^{2} \right ]  $$